# Java method invocation with list

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a function declared in a Java class with arguments (function parameters) extracted from a JSON File.

Java code:

```java
class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestRunner testRunner = new TestRunner();
        try {
            String path = (TestRunner.class.getResource("tests2.json")).getPath();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<Map<String, Object>> myObjects = mapper.readValue(Paths.get(path).toFile(),
                    new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
                    });
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map<String, Object> map : myObjects) {
                ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) map.get("args");
                System.out.println(new TestRunner().executeMethod(testRunner, "fun", arr.toArray()));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int fun(Integer[] arr) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
    }

    public int fun(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }

    public static Object executeMethod(Object objet, String methodName, Object[] parameters) throws Exception {
        Object result;
        Class[] typeParameters = null;
        if (parameters != null) {
            typeParameters = new Class[parameters.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; ++i) {
                typeParameters[i] = parameters[i].getClass();
            }
        }
        Method m = objet.getClass().getMethod(methodName, typeParameters);
        if (Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers())) {
            result = m.invoke(null, parameters);
        } else {
            result = m.invoke(objet, parameters);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

JSON File content:

```
[
  {
    "args": [1, 2, 3],
    "expected": 6
  },
  {
    "args": [[1, 2, 0]],
    "expected": 3
  }
]
```

It works fine with the first argument, but throws an exception with the second argument which is supposed to be treated as a list of integers in Java, but instead, it's passed to the method invocation with type: java.util.ArrayList

[Exception after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgjiC.png)

My question is how I can invoke the method with the correct type of argument which can be []Integer (case for the second args from json) by changing in code only in the executeMethod function.

Comment: Create a proper object to represent your args/expected combination (or better yet, use a sensible test framework like [Spock](https://spockframework.org) that has built-in support for parameterized testing).

Comment: Have you tried searching for how to convert an ArrayList to an array?

Comment: @kaya3 yes that's what i want, to convert that arraylist automaticaly, same as what happened with first args [1,2,3]

Comment: An ArrayList will never be converted to an array automatically, you have to write the code to convert it yourself.

Comment: I'm stuck with that issue, how to convert the arraylist to the array that can properly be passed to the function parameter, It's the same as predicting other types in the function executeMethod, but how i can change in the code to make it predict array

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn the basics of programming. When you have a function, in almost any language, the function needs parameters.

For example,

```
function makeCookies(flour, sugar, water){}
```

Now if you call `makeCookies(brick, broken_glass, battery_acid)` of course `makeCookies` will not work. You have to give it something of type `flour`, something of type `sugar`, and something of type `water`.

I hope you take that example seriously. This is the aspect of programming you do not comprehend. Once you understand the cookies metaphor, you will understand your problem. You tried to pass an `ArrayList` as parameters, but your function *requires* an integer *because you wrote it that way!* It's no big mystery! If you want your function to work, change the parameters that it requires to `ArrayList`! Or make another function if you need one for `Integer[]` and one for `ArrayList`.

Comment: The exception says no such method found with parameter java.util.ArrayList, the method fun is declared to accept list[] Integer or 3 Integers as parameters, and my question is how i can make the method invocation works fine with the Java.util.ArrayList or treat it as []Integer

Comment: That's not the point to declare the function to accept arraylist, I want it to convert that arraylist to the required parametre type, same as the first args [1,2,3], it was arraylist after reading it from the json file, and then was convertee to (Integer,Integer,Integer) using the loop in the executeMethod function, the second args [[1,2,0]], i want it to be treated as []Integer